# VBA Code not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that is not working properly.

```
Private Sub PrintNew_Click()
If Sheets("New").Range("email").Value = 0 Then MsgBox "Email Address Needs    to be Completed", vbInformation
If response = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
If MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then      Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("Disclosure").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
    If reponse = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

It works ok apart from the fact that if I click cancel on the option to print it still prints.

Please advise what needs to be amended.

Thanks in advance of any help.
John Davies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `response` is misspelled. In any case, I would place something like this ***before*** you print out, as it is much more idiomatic and requires one less conditional statement, as you can just print out afterwards. . :

```
If MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
```

Also, as mentioned by [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba) in the comments, you should consider using `Option Explicit` to prevent syntactical errors like yours. When `Option Explicit` is on, all variables must be declared *explicitly* with `Dim`/`ReDim` statements. Resultantly, attempting to use an undeclared variable as you did here will produce a compile-time error and clear direction as to the fault in your code.

Comment: I prefer `<> vbYes` as it gives you more stability. Also mention `Option Explicit` as a way of catching the misspelling.